# Hiding true URL from website visitor

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a php website. The various pages are distributed in various directories. Now, when I try to send the link to any page to a user, I have to put some URLs like `"www.mydomain.com/collection/latest/requestpage.html"` or `"www.mydomain.com/api/get/someapi.php"`. But this URL is too complicated. I want the pages to be referred via the URLs like `"www.mydomain.com/collection/requestpage"` and `"www.mydomain.com/someapi"` and also this same address to be displayed in the url bar of browser.

Thus, loading `"www.mydomain.com/collection/requestpage"` takes the user to `"www.mydomain.com/collection/latest/requestpage.html"` and loading `"www.mydomain.com/someapi"` takes the user to `"www.mydomain.com/api/get/someapi.php"`.

So,

1) I want the actual directory structure to be hidden  from the URL,

2) I want to hide the file type extension of the page being loaded, and

3) Show this modified URL in the address bar of the browser when accessing the specified page.

I know this can be done using a .htaccess file but I have never written anything like this before. I have a .htaccess file on my directory that redirects any request coming to "mydomain.com" to "www.mydomain.com". I want to add some code to this htaccess file to do the tasks I mentioned. Please suggest what requires to be done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) to remove the directories from the URL just add the following codes to your .htaccess file

```
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^FOLDER_NAME/ FOLDER_NAME%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Change FOLDER_NAME with your actual folder names

2) to remove extensions from the URL use following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
```

for html

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

for php

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

EDIT: while working with POST requests you have to change the RewriteRule as following

```
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=307,L]
```

3) You are done with what you wanted

Hope this helps.

Comment: For the hiding directories part.. It is working, I tested with one directory, but what did you mean by "for each of them write different code"? Do I have to rewrite the whole block for every directory? Or only the line containing RewriteRule?

Comment: Hello, the code worked, but there are a few webservices running, and post requests to those webservices are being redirected as get requests, and so the login is failing.. any workarounds for this?

Comment: not a problem any more, I solved it.. thank you once again.

Comment: Glad to know it helped you